# i cant get a image display before a ul li in a div

Tags: css, image, html-lists

i lost here. i am trying to get a simple tick box image display before a unodored list. i have tried background url and list style image, no good. i have changed the name of the div class. i have tried placing codes in either  one ul or one li. i can get display none to work but not images. 
`

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Cloudstrike</title>
    <meta charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div id = "wrapper">
        Piece of text inside a 500px width div centered on the page


<div id="site-title"><a href="#"></a></div>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Toys</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>

</header>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<br>

<section>
            <div class="banner">
            <img src="img/cloud-9-banner.png" class="bannerimg">
            </div>
<br>
<br>


            <div class = "one">one
            <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>





<ul>
        <li> list number 1 </li>
        <li> list number 2 </li>
        <li> list number 3 </li>
</ul>



        </div>

            <div class="two">two
    <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>

    <ul>
    <li> list number 1 </li>
    <li> list number 2 </li>
    <li> list number 3 </li>
</ul>
            </div>
            <div class="three">three
                    <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>
    <ul>
    <li> list number 1 </li>
    <li> list number 2 </li>
    <li> list number 3 </li>
</ul>
</div>

</secton>
<!-- end boxes -->

`

















css style
html {overflow:auto; 
    height:100%;
    font-size:62.5%;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}


body{
 margin: 0;
text-align: center;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#wrapper{
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: #005397 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 900px;

}
#site-title {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding:1em 0 0 1em;
    float:left;
    }

#site-title a {

    width:175px;
    height:53px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('../img/cloud-strike-logo.png') no-repeat;
        }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trek';
    src: url('fonts/Trek.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/Trek.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fonts/Trek.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('fonts/Trek.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('fonts/Trek.otf')  format('opentype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('fonts/Trek.svg#Trek') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }           


header { 
overflow: auto;
border: 2px solid #000;
width:80%;
height:100px;
margin: 0px auto;
color: #FFFFFF

}
nav{
display: block;
float: right;
margin:.4em 0;
width: auto;
}
nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0
}
nav li {
float: left;
position: relative;

}
nav a{
display: block;
line-height: 3.333em;
padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "arial,times new roman";
font-size:100%;
color:#fff;
font-weight:none;
}

section {
width: 80%;
margin:2 auto;
height:450px; 
display:block;
position: relative;
}
.banner {
background: #739ec2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff); 
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#c0c0c0), to(#ffffff)); /* older webkit syntax */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff); 

width:98%;
height:210px;
display:block;
margin-top: 1%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 2px;
}
img.bannerimg {clear: both;
    display: block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    padding:20px; 
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;

}

#main {
   display:block; 
    min-height:150px;
    background:#4f4f4f;
    margin:0 2em;


}





.one{
    width:30%; 
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border:0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

.two {
    width:30%;  
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border:0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

.three {
    width: 30%; 
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border:0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

.one ul
{


display:list-item;



}



.one ul li{
    background-image: url(..img/blue-check.png);


}




.one h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color:#256091;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: NettoOT arial;

    }
.two ul
{
    list-style: none;



}



.two ul li
{

background: url (../img/blue-check.png) no-repeat;

}




.two h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color:#256091;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: NettoOT arial;

    }
.three ul
{
    list-style: none;



}



.three ul li
{

background: url (../img/blue-check.png) no-repeat;

}




.three h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color:#256091;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: NettoOT arial;

    }   

#boxes p {
    font-size:100%;
    color:#333;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:20px 20px  20px;
    }



#footer{
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #6CEAF8;

}
#inner-box {
    display:block; 
    min-height:150px;
    background:#4f4f4f;
    margin-top:10px;

}
#greybox  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:1.3em;
 }
#greybox  li {

    background-position:0px;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#greybox  li a {
    font-size:80%;
    color:#fff;}

.footbox {
    width:22%; 
    margin-right:3%;  
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
.footbox h2{
    color: #b1a325;
}

.footboxlast {
    width:24%;  
    float:right; 
    display:inline;
}
.footboxlast h2{
    color: #b1a325;
}

#blackbar {display:block; 
    max-height:30px;
    background:#c5b41c;
    padding: 5px 20px; 5px 20px;
}

#blackbar p {font-size:70%;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
    }
#blackbar a {
    color:#256091;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i just want the tick box to appear before all ul li in all three boxes. if i get one done, i can manage the rest.i think. learning all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the image was invalid.

Look at the snippet, or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6ea3tbm/)

```css
html {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: #005397 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 900px;
}
#site-title {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
  float: left;
}
#site-title a {
  width: 175px;
  height: 53px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url('../img/cloud-strike-logo.png') no-repeat;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Trek';
  src: url('fonts/Trek.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/Trek.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/Trek.woff') format('woff'),
  /* Modern Browsers */
  url('fonts/Trek.ttf') format('truetype'),
  /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('fonts/Trek.otf') format('opentype'),
  /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('fonts/Trek.svg#Trek') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
}
header {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: #FFFFFF
}
nav {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: .4em 0;
  width: auto;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 3.333em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "arial,times new roman";
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: none;
}
section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2 auto;
  height: 450px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.banner {
  background: #739ec2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#c0c0c0), to(#ffffff));
  /* older webkit syntax */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c0c0c0, #ffffff);
  width: 98%;
  height: 210px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
img.bannerimg {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
#main {
  display: block;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #4f4f4f;
  margin: 0 2em;
}
.one {
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.three {
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.one ul {
  display: list-item;
}
.one ul li {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Blue_check.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.one h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #256091;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: NettoOT arial;
}
.two ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.two ul li {
  background: url (../img/blue-check.png) no-repeat;
}
.two h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #256091;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: NettoOT arial;
}
.three ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.three ul li {
  background: url (../img/blue-check.png) no-repeat;
}
.three h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #256091;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: NettoOT arial;
}
#boxes p {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px;
}
#footer {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #6CEAF8;
}
#inner-box {
  display: block;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #4f4f4f;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#greybox ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
#greybox li {
  background-position: 0px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
#greybox li a {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #fff;
}
.footbox {
  width: 22%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.footbox h2 {
  color: #b1a325;
}
.footboxlast {
  width: 24%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
.footboxlast h2 {
  color: #b1a325;
}
#blackbar {
  display: block;
  max-height: 30px;
  background: #c5b41c;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  5px 20px;
}
#blackbar p {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#blackbar a {
  color: #256091;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    Piece of text inside a 500px width div centered on the page


    <div id="site-title">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Jackets</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Caps</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Toys</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>

    <section>
      <section>
        <div class="banner">
          <img src="img/cloud-9-banner.png" class="bannerimg">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>


        <div class="one">one
          <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>





          <ul>
            <li>list number 1</li>
            <li>list number 2</li>
            <li>list number 3</li>
          </ul>



        </div>

        <div class="two">two
          <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>

          <ul>
            <li>list number 1</li>
            <li>list number 2</li>
            <li>list number 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="three">three
          <h1>Blue Bolt</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>list number 1</li>
            <li>list number 2</li>
            <li>list number 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </section>
      <!-- end boxes -->
```

Comment: i love rachel gallen!, that was giving me nightmares.i made a modification to your code. i added margin-left 20px and i added padding-left 20px in the one ul li and one ul i added list style outside none none and padding left 30px plus i got my image path to work.

Comment: hi can you tick the answer with a checkmark then? it will appear when you hover beside it. thanks. always happy to help :)

Comment: i just want the the symbol to appear beside the the line. i got that to work. now i have to figure out how to make my header nav font bigger. i set the overal font-size 62.5%.

Comment: how big do you want it http://jsfiddle.net/x6ea3tbm/1/ check this fiddle then check the checkmark

Comment: i made the font size 120% but it affecting the size of the cloud strike part. i am getting there but great to talk it out. 
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <p>Cloub Strike</p>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>

Comment: make a fiddle - what do you mean it's 'affecting' the cloud strike - explain and CHECK the CHECKMARK!!!

Comment: looks fine to me if you wanna move it over a bit just put a negative padding or margin to the right http://jsfiddle.net/x6ea3tbm/3

Comment: just checks no check marks. never thought to use negative spacing before. i am going use gradients behind the banner next and sort out the footer section, the footer is inside the section in chrome but not firefox or sublime, very strange. i have to media queries, exciting times ahead.

Comment: @Patrickkelly the checkmark i'm talking about is beside the answer. Mark it as correct! hover beside the answer and a tick will appear. click on it and it will turn green

Comment: there is no answer just, the check marks are for effect, they are list of products, send you an updated link tomorrow. its a computer store.

Comment: beside the answer on stack overflow!!!!! here!!!! look up accepted answer ! did you not take the tour??

Comment: i gain 15 points and you get 2 and a badge if you mark my answer as correct. now would you ever just do it!!! when you hover beside my answer to your question a tick will appear. All you have to do is click it.

Comment: rachel i am very sorry. new to this forum. thank you.

Comment: you will know for next time :)

Comment: i will. media queries next

Comment: do you know anything about media queries?

Comment: Yes loads send me a link to your new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189623/i-am-trying-to-use-media-queries-to-make-a-responsive-design-i-cant-them-it-to

Comment: edited the media query, worked it tonight. got explorer to disappear